# Windows laptop sound out supports *only* 48K sample rate?

Tags: windows, sample-rate

I'm trying to help a student switch his HP Windows-10 Laptop to a 44.1K playback sample rate, so he can run my software.  Unlike every Windows machine I've seen before, the Sound>Device>Advanced (sp?) panel shows *only* a 48K playback rate. No 44.1K choice.

One option would be to rewrite a bunch of my software to support 48K, and indeed, 48K seems to be the default for every Windows machine I've seen in the last 5 years, but that's going to take time, and it seems like there should be an easy way to fix this.  Maybe... enabling a different interface? Wasapi? The student has already updated his sound drivers, which he tells me made no difference.

Any suggestions appreciated!

Comment: I'd hazard a guess that some other piece of software has removed the other options, because it can't cope when the setting has changed.  Or perhaps the options aren't presented if the sound subsystem is in use?  (Might be worth trying Safe Mode.)

Comment: votes to close: fair enough. Can anyone suggest a stack exchange site on which this would be more appropriate?